# How to easily publish non-Maven artifacts from Jenkins to Bintray?

Tags: jenkins, bintray

Is there an easy way to publish non-Maven artifacts to a generic repository on Bintray from a Jenkins job? I've been reading through [Deploying Maven and Gradle snapshots to OJO](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26083425) but that applies to Maven-compatible artifacts / Maven repositories only.

I'm aware that I could use the [Bintray REST API](https://bintray.com/docs/api.html), but that's a bit too low-level for my taste. I'm wondering if there's something for Jenkins like the [Artifactory Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin), but for use with Bintray.

The closest thing I've found so far is a Bintray REST API wrapper like this [Perl module](http://search.cpan.org/~mithun/Bintray-API-0.02/lib/Bintray/API.pm), but I don't like that either as I'd need to install the module on all Jenkins nodes then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Bintray, there is [Bintray Java Client](http://github.com/bintray/bintray-client-java). We are going to release the new version, which supports file upload and signing in the following week or so.

Comment: That looks promising, although for my purpose your [Bash example](https://github.com/bintray/bintray-examples/tree/master/bash-example) looks even more suitable, as I cannot guarantee that all our Jenkins nodes have Java installed. Are there also plans to extend the Bash example into something like a Bash library, maybe using a tool like the great [jq command-line JSON processor](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)?

Comment: I, personally, not into bash programming, but we gladly accept contributions :-)